# WPF custom context menu (resource dictionary)

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I've created a custom style for the context menu. But I have to put 3 lines of code under each widget(Textbox):

```
<TextBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu/>
</TextBox.ContextMenu>
```

Why do I have to do that ? My tooltip style works without any extra code.

My context menu code:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Color x:Key="BackgroundColor" A="255" R="19" G="19" B="19"/>

    <BitmapImage x:Key="BiCut" UriSource="Images/cut.tif"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="BiCopy" UriSource="Images/copy.tif"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="BiPaste" UriSource="Images/paste.tif"/>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BorderBrush" Color="#ECECEC"/>

    <Style TargetType="ContextMenu">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#2468d9" Padding="2" Background="#131313">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="20">
                                <Image Source="{StaticResource BiCut}" Width="20"/>
                                <Button Content="Ausschneiden" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Strg+X" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controls do not have `ContextMenu` by default (check property - it is `null`). So your style will be not applied to any Control.
Tooltip is `null` by defult, but it will be filled by `TooltipService` if it is necessary.

There is no service to fill your `ContextMenu` for all of your element. Use a default style for this (for `Control`).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a default `Style` for your `TextBox` and add that `ContextMenu` in `Style`. In this way you will have that `ContextMenu` for every `TextBox` you will add in your application and you won't have to add these three lines everywhere.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >
     <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```